# send a custom email containing a table with images and texts in swift

Tags: ios, swift, email

I want to send an email from my ios app containing a custom body with a table full of images and texts as showing bellow. Do you know how to do so guys ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you just incorporate a share feature to share the image via email.

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it's not an image. The infos in table are dynamic and I want to send them as an html email so the links can be copied.